# PHP - How to use checkdate with if statement

Tags: php

How do I use `checkdate` to return an error message if the date
provided is invalid?

```
if(checkdate($month, $day, $year) != "true")
{
    $error = "Date invalid";
}
```

Comment: `checkdate()` returns boolean `true` or boolean `false`, but never the string `"true"` or the string `"false"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this,  `checkdate` — Validate a Gregorian date. Returns **TRUE** if the date given is valid; otherwise returns **FALSE**.

```
if(!checkdate($month, $day, $year)){
   echo $error = "Date invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`checkdate` returns a `bool` - you don't need to compare it to anything, just evaluate it:

```
if(!checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
    $error = "Date invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking for boolean false using === rather than == to a string but otherwise you're fine. So the corrected code would be :

```
if (checkdate($month, $day, $year) === false) {
    $error = "Date invalid";
}
```

or, if you have a penchant for one-liners:

```
if (checkdate($month, $day, $year) === false) $error = "Date invalid";
```

Comment: I agree with other posters that if (!checkdate($month, $day, $year)) $error = "Date invalid"; is better but wanted to point out that if you're going to compare with booleans you should think about using === and !==.